# Rediska PHP

Tags: php, redis

Подскажите как вытянуть значение из hash по ключу.
В console redis-cli это делается так: HGET user.info 3, где 3 является ключом

Answer (score 1):

Делается так:

```
$user_info = new Rediska_Key_Hash('user.info');
var_dump($user_info->Get(1));
Где **Get(1)** извлекает значения по ключу 1
```